# Basic Geometry and Area of the right triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Forgive me for the terrible formatting.Also i am having trouble uploading images.

[A right angled Triangle](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/4OYFP)

So in Triangle PRQ which expression is correct?

$$\dfrac 12 PR \cdot RQ \quad \text{or} \quad \dfrac 12 RM \cdot PQ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael's answer is perfect, but I'm just writting this to help you visualize this a little better to convince yourself.

Look at this:

[image]

Note that both rectangles (U=blue+black and V=red+black) have twice the area of your $PRQ$ triangle, so they are the same. The area of $U$ is $PQ\cdot RM$ and the area of $V$ is $PR\cdot RQ$, since they are the same, then $PQ\cdot RM=PR\cdot RQ$ and half of this is the area of your triangle. Sorry for my terrible drawing.

You could also see this as two separate triangles, $A=\Delta PRM$ and $B=\Delta RMQ$, then $area(A)=\frac{1}{2}PM\cdot RM$ and $area(B)=\frac{1}{2} MQ\cdot RM$, so $$area(\Delta PRQ)=area(A)+area(B)=\frac{1}{2}(PM\cdot RM+MQ\cdot RM)=\frac{1}{2}((PM+MQ)\cdot RM),$$ but $PM+MQ=PQ$.

Comment: When we consider angle RPQ as theta, PR would be base and RQ would be height. I am wondering that when angle RQP be theta then shouldnt RQ be the base and PR be height ? Then howcome 1/2 * RM *PQ is also right ?

Comment: It doesn't matter who among $RP$ and $RQ$ you consider as the base, because the other one will be the height and the formula can be applied the same way, because things commute here.

Comment: Listen if angle RQP is theta the RQ is base and PR is height. So in whichever case RM doesnt come into the expression . So how come 1/2 * RM*PQ is also correct ?

Comment: You can see this as two separate triangles PRM and RMQ, then apply the formula, sum the areas and note that $PQ=PM+MQ$.

Comment: Edited, see it.

Comment: Thanks you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

For right-angled triangle $PRQ$, where $\measuredangle PRQ=90^{\circ}$ and $RM$ is an altitude we have:
 $$S_{\Delta PQR}=\frac{1}{2}PR\cdot RQ=\frac{1}{2}RM\cdot PQ$$
because we can think also that $RQ$ is an altitude and $PR$ is the side for which we drew this altitude.

Comment: How come ? Could you explain ?

Comment: I am not that into mathamatics.i would be glad if you could explain a bit more.

Comment: @user33699 $S_{\Delta}=\frac{a\cdot h}{2}$, where $h$ is an altitude of the triangle and $a$ is a length of the side, to which the altitude is transferred. Do you know this fact?

Comment: Yes i do know this.

Comment: @user33699 If so try to read the line with  $S_{\Delta PQR}=...$. There written exactly which you know!

Comment: But if PQ is the base and RM is the altitude, then wont the area of triangle RMP be left out ?

Comment: Actually i do know the formula for the area of a triangle but if we take PQ as base and RM as height, wont the area of triangle RMQ be left out ?

Comment: @user33699 I really don't understand your troubles. You wish to find $S_{\Delta PQR}$. You know that $PQ$ is the base and $RM$ is the altitude. Use the formula and find the area. Why do you think about $\Delta RMP$? This triangle has no any relation with your problem.

Comment: When we consider angle RPQ as theta, PR would be base and RQ would be height. I am wondering that when angle RQP be theta then shouldnt RQ be the base and PR be height ? Then howcome 1/2 * RM *PQ is also right ?

Comment: @user33699 Yes of cause. $\frac{1}{2}\cdot RM\cdot PQ$ is the area of the triangle $PQR$ and $\frac{1}{2}\cdot PR\cdot RQ$ is an area of $\Delta PQR$.